# Why keyof a picked type is not picked keys in function generic?

Tags: typescript

```
interface Test {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}


let arr: string[] = []

function test<S extends Pick<Test, 'a' | 'b'>, T extends keyof S>(val: T[]) {
    arr = val // it's not ok
}
```

[image]

PlayGround: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=27&pln=15&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFDKHJwBcyWUoA5gNwFEBGZIArgLYPR1HIJkMB7AQBsIcEHQC+eGaOxwoUMhWoBtALrIAvMg0yYLEAjDABIZJCwAeAMrIIAD0ggAJhmQAFYAgDWV9FgANMgA5HAhyAA+oQwhAHzBqPZOEK7uPhAAngIwyDZxABQAbnDCZKgaAJS49IQKUNrIJcLIAPStyIaOSAAOkC72igJQAIR40jJgmT0odjpevv6YYMFhEdEhsXF0UzNojRnZuTYyCGZYTaXlGo169Y3NbR0A7gAWmcjA2MDuAj4A-EA

But, if I don't use function, it's ok:

```
type S = Pick<Test, 'a' | 'b'>;
type T = keyof S

const val: T[] = []
arr = val // why it is ok?
```

And, When I declare the generic S separately, there is also no error:

```
type S = Pick<Test, 'a' | 'b'>;

function test<T extends keyof S>(val: T[]) {
    arr = val // it is ok
}
```

Comment: Note that “it’s not ok” isn’t sufficient for this to be a [mre]. Please [edit] to include the text of any error in the question as well.

Comment: @jcalz sorry, I have added the error picture

Comment: A picture is not appropriate here either; please include the text of the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the generic type `S` can have more keys than just `"a"` and `"b"` — that's what the `extends` keyword means in that position: that the generic type `S` must be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) by `Pick<Test, "a" | "b">` (not that it **only** has keys `"a"` and `"b"`).

TypeScript is [structurally-typed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) (more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes-func.html#structural-typing)), so supplying a generic type that satisfies `Pick<Test, "a" | "b">` that **also** has an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) of `symbol` keys with `unknown` values will be accepted by the compiler…

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true&ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=21&pc=75#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFACQcAXMllKAOYDchARqSAK4C2d0tBCpdA9rwBsIcELQC+ePEOxwoUUuSoBtALrIAvMlW08MJiARhgvEMkhYAPAGVkEAB6QQAEwzIACsAQBrC+iwAaZAAiOCDkAB9guiCAPkDUWwcIZ1cvCABPXhhkKxiACgA3OAFSVFUASlxCWSgNZCKBcUkwdIAHFAAxfjr8IgUwChAaekZWdihOJTT0hXS2QRVSfS8QXgB3UTwxHQQTLGRQVqYwUjzprOQu3nLVOqUrOb4BPKCYfiDywJCgr+iVHXMYAsV0C52yV3yh2O5WoyAA9HDkAB5LyBOjHMiPQQHVyrGQYDDASggOB0IRmXhkAZUPBAA)

```ts
type Foo = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  [key: symbol]: unknown;
};

const input: (keyof Foo)[] = [Symbol("foo"), "a", "b"];

test<Foo, keyof Foo>(input); // Ok, but symbol is not assignable to string
```

…but `symbol` is not assignable to `string`, so it would be a type error to accept an array of such values (or any other non-string value).

In the second code block example of your question you provided this code and question:

```ts
type S = Pick<Test, "a" | "b">;
type T = keyof S;

const val: T[] = [];
arr = val; // why it is ok?
```

There, `S` is a type that looks like `{ a: string; b: number }` and T is the union of its keys, which is `"a" | "b"`. An array of `"a"` and `"b"` values are assignable to `string`, so there's no problem there.

A modified version of your `test` function that uses these types would look like this…

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&noErrorTruncation=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5mQbwFACQcAXMllKAOYDchARqSAK4C2d0tBCpdA9rwBsIcELQC+ePEOxwoUUuSoBtALrIAvMlW08MJiARhgvEMkhYAFADc4A0hYDWEAJ68YyAArAEDgDzosABpkACI4EOQAH1C6EIA+AEpVBNxCWSgNZBsBcUkwZwAHFAAxfkz8IgUwChAaekZWdihOJSdnBWc2QRVSfQcQXgB3UTwxHQQTLGRQAqYweza3ZFLeJLVNJQBlTr4BCxCYfhCE4LCQ09iVHXMwCxm5hNogA)

```ts
function test(val: (keyof Pick<Test, "a" | "b">)[]) {
  arr = val;
}
```

> Note that `keyof Pick<Test, "a" | "b">` is just `"a" | "b"`.

…and attempting to provide an array of values that includes a non-string will produce a compiler diagnostic error:

```ts
type Foo = {
  a: string;
  b: number;
  [key: symbol]: unknown;
};

const input: (keyof Foo)[] = [Symbol("foo"), "a", "b"];

test(input); /* Error
     ~~~~~
Argument of type '(keyof Foo)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '("a" | "b")[]'.
  Type 'keyof Foo' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'.
    Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'.(2345) */
```

Comment: Yeah, looking at this on mobile I was thinking `symbol` would be the way to show the issue